# Which version of RAD Editor is Sitecore 6 using?

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore6

I want to know which version of RAD Editor is Sitecore 6 using? this page has many version but which is in Sitecore 6 I don't know [see about version info here](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet/editor/whatsnew.html)

Comment: @jitendra: sorry what is the question ?

Comment: i added more info to question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have a project running Site 6.1 and the version of RadEditor.Net2.dll is 7.2.0.0 and for RadSpell.NET2.dll it is 3.2.0.0.

To get these numbers, I simply opened the properties window for each of these assemblies and inspected the Version tab.